# Error: Unexpected annotation generated by the Firebase Functions. This should never happen

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I came across this error while deploying the function using

firebase deploy --only functions

at end of deployment,[image]

Not sure, what could be wrong as I didn't see any source for this error. any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? So that the community can further assist you on your error.

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably because you are using an outdated version of the `firebase` command on the CLI. I experienced the exact same error as you because of this.

Upgrading to the latest version of the package [firebase-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools) (this is the package that provides the firebase command on CLI) should solve your issue.

You can check your current version with:

```bash
firebase --version
```

Be careful, if you are using both NPM and Yarn, the dependency must be updated for both dependency managers since each maintains a separate cache:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
yarn global add firebase-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me when I used `functions.handler.auth.user.onCreate`.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.halloWorld = functions.handler.auth.user.onCreate(
    async (user) => {
       functions.logger.log(`added ${user.displayName}`);
    });
```

But when I use `functions.auth.user().onCreate`, it works.
I found `functions.handler.auth.user.onCreate` in some example code and it took me some time to resolve the issue.

Comment: yes. I am not sure why handler method not work. I have used without handler option.